# Dynamic/non-standard resolutions for PDF in Xcode Asset Catalogs

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, pdf, xcasset

I love using the new PDF vector images in Xcode 6 Asset Catalogs a.k.a xcassets. I know that on iOS, these PDF's are rendered down at build time to @1x, @2x etc. PNG's and then embedded into the runtime asset catalog.

However I need at least two different sets of sizes: standard and double-sized. Effectively, I would need @1x, @2x and @3x for the standard icons and @2x, @4x and @6x for the double-sized icons.

Question: **how can I get these non-standard sizes from the single PDF?** I don't necessarily need a fully dynamic sizing, just two sets of sizes. If Xcode 6 doesn't support this, are there any easy tools that will simply double the size of the PDF?

Comment: Why would a vector image need different sizes? The entire idea is that you *don't* need to manually resize them, where it is mandatory  with bitmaps.

Comment: Well, yes, but Xcode *renders* the vector image into bitmaps optimised for the different Retina screens at build time for iOS deployment. I could keep the vector image as a separate, non asset catalog resource, but I want to avoid that since I want to avoid rendering them at runtime.